# Не могу извлечь данные из тега

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

ищу в этом куске `<div class="chart chart__temperature" style="height: 77px;width: 660px"><div class="values" style="height: 77px">`
этот текст **height: 77px;width: 660px**

вот как написал в php

```
    $fileerror = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ERROR.txt";
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/parse.txt";
    $modif = time()-@filemtime ("$filename");
    if(!file_exists($filename) || $modif>"1")
      {
       $url                   = file_get_contents("https://site.ru");    
       $handle                = fopen ("$filename", "w");   
       fwrite($handle, $url);    
       fclose($handle);
      }
    $url = (file_get_contents($filename) == null) ? file_get_contents($fileerror) : file_get_contents($filename);

preg_match_all('#<div class="chart chart__temperature" style="(.*?)">#si',$url,$razm);

for ($i=0; $i<1; $i++) {

echo $razm[0][$i];

echo $razm[1][$i];
}
```

В регулярке на сайте [https://www.bl2.ru/](https://www.bl2.ru/programing/regular.html) получилось извлечь то что нужно,  а вот echo с разными ключами пустоту выдают.
Подскажите как правильно извлечь данные из тега  `div style`

Comment: Потмоу что сайт эскейпит специальные символы в регулярке, а вы нет?

Comment: видимо нет... эскейпит - это что? спецсимволы это кавычки? или тот двойной нижний пробел?

Comment: Мне кажется достаточно в вашем случае достаточно поэскейпить `=`, сделать его `\=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Некоторые символы в регулярных выражениях имеют особый смысл (например, точка, звездочка), в вашем случае это символ `=`. Его следует заэскейпить, то есть указать, что он должен восприниматься не как управляющий символ, а как есть:

```
$url = '<div class="chart chart__temperature" style="height: 77px;width: 660px"><div class="values" style="height: 77px">';
preg_match_all('#<div class\="chart chart__temperature" style\="(.*?)">#si',$url,$razm);
print_r($razm);
```

Выводит:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <div class="chart chart__temperature" style="height: 77px;width: 660px">
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => height: 77px;width: 660px
        )

)
```

Comment: А с какой версии php символ равенства внутри шаблона считается спецсимволом? _(до версии 7.3 он простой литерал)_ И какое для него задано действие?

Comment: Preg_quote эскейпит = всегда. Не знаю откуда у вас информация про версию.

Comment: К тому же знак равенства используется в проверках назад и вперёд.

Comment: В проверках используется не один знак `=`, а последовательность символов. Как например `\pL` - каждый из них означает сам себя, и экранированию не подлежит. Preg_quote - __вероятно__ такое её поведение подлежит корректировке.